# MKMarkerAnnotationView Doesn't Show

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Setting up a map view with annotation of nearby cafes.
But when I try to custom the annotations using `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, nothing shows on the map view.
and when I log the marker, the frame is (0 0; 0 0);

I tried pin too, still didn't work.

I set up delegate on storyboard already.

I also debugged the view controller there are marker views but it is not displaying them because the width and height are zero ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.cafeMap setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    self.cafes = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self fetchData];

    [self.cafeMap registerClass:[MKAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:@"marker"];



}

-(void)fetchData{

    [self.networkManager fetchCafeData:^(NSArray * _Nonnull businesses) {
        for (NSDictionary* cafeInfo in businesses) {
            Cafe *cafe = [[Cafe alloc]initWithCafeInfo:cafeInfo];
            [self.cafes addObject:cafe];
        }

        for (Cafe *cafe in self.cafes) {
            [self.cafeMap addAnnotation:cafe];
        }
        [self.cafeMap showAnnotations:self.cafes animated:YES];
    }];

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    MKMarkerAnnotationView *marker = [[MKMarkerAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"marker"];
    marker = (MKMarkerAnnotationView*) [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"marker" forAnnotation:annotation];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

    marker.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;

    [marker setEnabled:YES];
    [marker setCanShowCallout:YES];
    NSLog(@"MARKER:%@",marker);
    return marker;


}
```

This is the output:

> MARKER:<MKAnnotationView: 0x7f9fa3f333b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000253d220>>

Answer (score 0):

Note that your message says that it is a `MKAnnotationView`. That is because you have registered `MKAnnotationView` for your identifier rather than `MKMarkerAnnotationView`. You want:

```
[self.cafeMap registerClass:[MKMarkerAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:@"marker"];
```

---

As an aside, you should be able to simplify `viewForAnnotation` to:

```
MKAnnotationView *marker = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"marker" forAnnotation:annotation];
```

---

Personally, I’d move the configuration of the annotation view into its own subclass:

```
static NSString * const cafeClusteringIdentifier = @"cafe";

@interface CafeAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView
@end

@implementation CafeAnnotationView
- (instancetype)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
        self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
        self.canShowCallout = true;
        self.clusteringIdentifier = cafeClusteringIdentifier;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    [super setAnnotation:annotation];
    self.clusteringIdentifier = cafeClusteringIdentifier;
}
@end
```

By doing this, I avoid bloating my view controller with code for configuring annotation views.

Note, I’m setting the [`clusteringIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/2867297-clusteringidentifier?language=objc) so that you enjoy that behavior of the `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.

And then I’d register that class for [`MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdefaultannotationviewreuseidentifier?language=objc):

```
[self.cafeMap registerClass:[CafeAnnotationView class] forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier];
```

The benefit of using `MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier` is that you don’t have to implement `viewForAnnotation` at all. Delete your implementation of that method entirely. In iOS 11 and later, you only need to implement `viewForAnnotation` if you need to do something special like having multiple custom reuse identifiers for multiple types of annotations.

Anyway, that yields:

[image: cafes with callouts]